# Get data from smart card using node-pcsclite

Tags: node.js, smartcard, smartcard-reader, pcsc

Im trying to read from a smart card using node-pcsclite library and "BIT4ID miniLector EVO" reader.

How could I get the cards content? Im new at working with smart cards and id appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Here is the code im using and what i get.

```
var pcsc = require('pcsclite');

var pcsc = pcsc();
pcsc.on('reader', function(reader) {

    console.log('New reader detected', reader.name);

    reader.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Error(', this.name, '):', err.message);
    });

    reader.on('status', function(status) {
        console.log('Status(', this.name, '):', status);
        /* check what has changed */
        var changes = this.state ^ status.state;
        if (changes) {
            if ((changes & this.SCARD_STATE_EMPTY) && (status.state & this.SCARD_STATE_EMPTY)) {
                console.log("card removed");/* card removed */
                reader.disconnect(reader.SCARD_LEAVE_CARD, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Disconnected');
                    }
                });
            } else if ((changes & this.SCARD_STATE_PRESENT) && (status.state & this.SCARD_STATE_PRESENT)) {
                console.log("card inserted");/* card inserted */
                reader.connect({ share_mode : this.SCARD_SHARE_SHARED }, function(err, protocol) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log('Protocol(', reader.name, '):', protocol);
                        reader.transmit(Buffer.from([0x00, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20]), 40, protocol, function(err, data) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            } else {
                                console.log('Data received', data);
                                // reader.close();
                                // pcsc.close();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    reader.on('end', function() {
        console.log('Reader',  this.name, 'removed');
    });
});

pcsc.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('PCSC error', err.message);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The program you show here, assumes that 32 bytes from an automagically selected file on the card can simply be read without any complications. This is an unrealistic simple scenario, which would not justify the effort for involving a smart card.

Unfortunately smarts card are infamously difficult to learn, since you get so little information in case of an error. A good approach is to find an open source project and learn from functional code, but this does not necessarily cover the process to create a working card.